# Cannot get External URL from UploadFileWithIDSelector object

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to create an action that opens a tab, inserts an uploaded file's external URL into the tab, and navigates to that URL just like as if a user clicked the Files button and then clicked one of the File's titles and it opened up the tab with the contents of the file.

Here is the code I used to get the External Link. Please note that I have the FileID stored as an extension column in the InventoryItem table for this example:

```
PXView item = Base.Views["Item"];

InventoryItem item = PXSelect<InventoryItem, Where<InventoryItem.inventoryCD,
   Equal<Current<InventoryItem.inventoryCD>>>>
   .Select(Base, Base.Views["Item"].Cache.Current);

InventoryItemExt itemext = item.Cache.GetExtension<InventoryItemExt>(item);
UploadFileWithIDSelector fileInfo = PXSelect<UploadFileWithIDSelector,
   Where<UploadFileWithIDSelector.fileID, 
   Equal<Current<PX.Objects.IN.InventoryItemExt.usrDefaultSpecID>>>
   .Select(Base, itemext.UsrDefaultSpecID);
```

I then try to execute the following code to open the page using the ExternalLink:

```
throw new PXRedirectToUrlException(fileInfo.ExternalLink, "");
```

This results in the following error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Is the DAC unable to directly get the external link? Is there any way to fix this so it retrieves the external link? Is there another (possibly simpler) way to retrieve the external link of an uploaded file?

Thanks

Comment: Probably not related to your issue but you are passing arguments to your BQL query as if you were using Required<> and not Current<>. If that works, that means that your current record is the same is the one you are specifying. Moreover, the first query to get the inventory Item is flawed as a Required<> would expect an InventoryCD and not a complete object. You could most likely get what you want with: `InventoryItem item =  Base.Item.Current;` and `InventoryItemExt itemext = PXCache<InventoryItem>.GetExtension<InventoryItemExt>(item);
 `, or only with the last line without the argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to redirect to the file with this syntax:

```
throw new PXRedirectToUrlException(PXRedirectToFileException.BuildUrl(fileInfo.fileID), "");
```

Consider using this syntax to redirect since you don't need a message:

```
throw new PXRedirectToFileException(fileInfo.fileID, true);
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you. Just one correction, .fileID should be .FileID since you are referencing the value, not the type. I ended up using throw new PXRedirectToUrlException(PXRedirectToFileException.BuildUrl(fileInfo.FileID), PXBaseRedirectException.WindowMode.NewWindow, ""); because the customer wanted it in a new window. Thanks a ton again for your help!